# Removing link from botdetect captcha in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I am using Botdetect captcha, But i need to remove the link they have given below the image captcha, how to remove it

```
<a href="//captcha.org/captcha.html?codeigniter" title="BotDetect CAPTCHA Library for CodeIgniter" style="display: block !important; height: 10px !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; font-size: 9px !important; line-height: 9px !important; visibility: visible !important; font-family: Verdana, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Verdana Ref, sans-serif !important; vertical-align: middle !important; text-align: center !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: #f8f8f8 !important; color: #606060 !important;">BotDetect CAPTCHA Library for CodeIgniter</a>
```

Here is the image [image]

Comment: is the link  auto generated?

Comment: yes its auto generated

Comment: try some jquery and remove the title attribute

Comment: Read BotDetect Capcha FAQ [How do I remove the link to your site from the Captcha image?](https://captcha.com/captcha-faq.html#usage-free-link)

Answer (score 5):

add code top site

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[title ~= 'BotDetect']").removeAttr("style");
    $("a[title ~= 'BotDetect']").removeAttr("href");
    $("a[title ~= 'BotDetect']").css('visibility', 'hidden');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used botdetect captcha for non commercial use,

where I was able to successfully removed the link and title .

Path of file to be modified ,

vendor/captcha-com/examples/captcha/lib/botdetect/CaptchaInculdes.php

```
private static function iqy23{
return '';
}
```

And

```
public static function GetHelpLinkText($_1qfl5bimwvnl8fd7, $_iitpwcsaaap742gstb7q5) {
return '';
}
```

Return blank in above two functions.

Hope it helps someone looking for non commercial use or who is willing to understand the algorithm ,

it is always recommendable to purchase the paid version for commercial use.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the below links. I suggest you can convert the help link mode to image instead. It will hide the text from getting displayed and instead captcha will be clickable.

https://captcha.com/doc/java/captcha-options.html#captcha_help_link_mode

https://captcha.com/license/captcha-free-version-limitations.html#link

Answer (score 0):

You can add  HelpLinkMode property with "Image" value
Like this:
<BotDetect:WebFormsCaptcha ID="ExampleCaptcha" UserInputID="CaptchaCode" runat="server" HelpLinkMode="Image"/>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can make a div over the legend:

```
<botDetect:captcha id="miCaptcha" userInputID="captchaCode" codeLength="4" imageWidth="150" imageStyle="GRAFFITI2"/>
<div id="tapa" style="background-color: #ffffd9;height: 10px;width: 150px;position: relative;top: -10px;"></div>
```